# Restrict people from running production pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm evaluating gitlab community edition as a self hosted version. Everything is fine with the product except anyone who has access to pipelines (master or admin) can run deployment on production.

I saw their issue board and i see that this is a feature that will not be coming to gitlab anytime soon.

See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20261

For now, I plan on deploying my spring boot applications using the following strategy.

- A separate runner installed on the production server
- There will be an install script with instructions some where in production server
- `gitlab-runner` user will only have permissions to run the above specific script (Somehow).
- Have validations in the script for `GITLAB_USER_NAME` variable.

But I also see that there are disadvantages in this approach.

- `GITLAB_USER_NAME` is an environment variable which can be overridden easily thus compromising the validation.
- Things are complicated when introducing new prod servers.
- Too many changes apart from `.gitlab-ci.yml`... CI/CD was supposed to be simple not painful...

Do I have any alternate approaches or hacks for this...?

Comment: I think you should rethink about you split roles. The job for deploying should be only on `master` or `release/*` - and that branches should be protected. Therefore you give the "master" role for that project only to who can deploy to production, and leave the others as developers

Comment: I think you didn't get the question right. Any developer can create a branch and have their own `.gitlab-ci.yml`. This means they can literally do whatever they want. there is no control I have in them writing jobs that deploy in production on their own branch.

Comment: You can use protected branches and protected variables - I suppose there are credentials to deploy, and Gitlab CI injects them? Then if these credentials are marked as protected, they will be injected only in protected branches.

If there is no credentials, nobody stops the developer to do that from his PC